# Compare a substring array in string array in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

So I have a table, first column is substring array, second column is string array :

```
      A1                  A2                          A3
----------------------------------------------------------
I am a police   ||   My name is Jean             ||  TRUE
Nothing mine    ||   I am a police and a cook    ||  TRUE
is              ||   bla bla bla                 ||  FALSE
```

So it will compare the A2 and A1. if any substring from column A1 does exist in any string in A2, then A3 will show TRUE

Im using SUMPRODUCT, SEARCH, and ISNUMBER like :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,A2)))>0
```

But the results are not 100% correct. Any build in formula can do this ? (without macro)

Comment: look [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Comment: @Blueblazer172 I have used that before, it keeps showing VALUES and NAS

Comment: What exactly does A1 contain? You appear to have three values all in the same cell here, separated by line breaks. But then are the entries in A2 also contained within a single cell? If so, why are there then three results in "cell" A3?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with VBA code.
Add new module and put this code :

```
Sub matchIt()

Dim lastRow_String As String
Dim lastRow_SubString As String


With ActiveSheet
  lastRow_String = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  lastRow_SubString = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For i = 1 To lastRow_String ' B string

    For j = 1 To lastRow_SubString 'A substring

        If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value, ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 1).Value) > 0 Then

            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = "True"

        End If

        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = "False"
        End If

    Next j

Next i


End Sub
```